# Labview math operations with fractions

Tags: labview

Is there a simple way to do multiplication by a fraction in Labview? If I want to multiply by like 9/5s I could obviously put 1.8 and multiply that or do a separate operation to first divide 9 by 5 and then multiply the result from that, but the first loses clarity and the second is cumbersome. I'd like to be able to just input like '9/5' and have Labview work with that.

Comment: If the data type is a float, just multiply by 9/5, i.e. 1.8, as shown in NMech's answer ... If it is an integer, you can avoid the conversion by doing classic integer math: multiply by 9 first, then divide by 5. However do check for overflow. As for the rounding error: You have 2 options for improved rounding: option 1: if the product is positive, add half the dividend to the divisor (if the product would be negative, subtract instead of adding). Option 2: keep the remainder from each division, and add it into the dividend in the next operation. Option 2 limits accumulated error to <divisor.

Comment: also note, for signed integer division, there are 4 overflow cases, if I remember right, so check them all

Comment: If you're talking about how to let the user input an expression like "9/5", you could parse it with a Regex ... count the number of "/", and if exactly 1, split the string on "/", first part is dividend, second part is divisor, etc etc

Answer (score 2):

This is very much depended on version but you can try:

- [**formula nodes**](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000x30HCAQ&l=en-US)

In your case it would look like
[image]

- **mathscript** (if you have the license)

[image]

However another option would be to:

- **create a Subvi with a meaningful icon**. (this is probably the more labview way, although its a pain it the a** to keep all the files in order, if you go down that road.

[image]

That has a very basic block diagram

[image]

However IMHO this is overkill.

To be honest, if you plan to work with Labview a lot I suggest you buy the bullet and start using the palettes.